# Kubuntu 19.10 touchpad freezes

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, touchpad, 19.10

I have installed Kubuntu version 19.10 on my laptop (Acer Aspire A515-52G) and it works perfectly.
But one thing I have experienced is, that sometimes my touchpad freezes when I move the cursor.
The cursor hangs a second and when i move the cursor again every works fine.
At first I didn't notice any pattern when it occurs, but now I think it occurs mainly when the laptop is under load.

Under Windows the touchpad works without any problems, so a hardware defect can be neglected.

I have searched through the internet and did find a few articles that drive attention to the nvidia drivers. But I have tried multiple drivers:

1. nvidia-drivers-435
2. nvidia-drivers-430
3. xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

But none of these had an effect on the bug.

Comment: Happens when I accidentally trail a finger onto the right side of the mushpad. When I tap on the left side or left-click the cursor wakes up.